# Coloring squares either red or blue

Tags: visual

Color each square either red or blue so that no red square is halfway between two other red squares.  Similarly, no blue square can be halfway between two other blue squares.

[image: Eight squares in a straight line]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

either I am wrong or its fairly simple ?

> [image] OR [image]

> B R B R R B R B  OR  R B R B B R B R

> A similar [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121503/a-special-binary-string) gives 2 more valid answers as @IVO commented

> R R B B R R B B  or  B B R R B B R R

> [image] OR [image]

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: I like the symmetry in your solutions.

Comment: That's perhaps why I found it fairly quickly as symmetry was core to my designers living, Thus in balance on the LEVEL is looking at it both ways

Comment: I guess RRBBRRBB also works

Comment: @Ivo that is the answer to the spin off so yes those are others TWO