# A special binary string

Tags: mathematics, optimization

I was inspired by this [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121499/coloring-squares-either-red-or-blue).

What is the longest binary string of "0" and "1" you can form such that no "0" is halfway between two other "0" and no "1" is halfway between two other "1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> **8**, example: 01100110

Remark:

> For every finite alphabet (eg. 0,1,...,n-1), there is always a finite maximal length W(n,3)-1 among strings without 3-term arithmetic progressions. This is Van der Waerden's theorem:
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @justhalf Because I don't need reputation points for being able to link to Wikipedia

Comment: Oh, you mean the question is too easy? Haha, ok.

Comment: @justhalf The question itself is not too easy, but pointing to a source that contains a solution is too easy.

Comment: I made a harder version of this question.